# Почему я получаю ошибку? Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Я получаю JSON файл с API UNSPLASH, когда рендерю файл в html, получаю ошибку на 12 строке,
вот код:

```
const srchPhotos = document.querySelector('#searchPhotos');
srchPhotos.onclick = function() {
    let client_id = 'Access Key';
    let query = document.getElementById('search').value;
    let url = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=${client_id}&query=${query}`;

    fetch(url)
        .then(function(data) {
            return data.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            data.results.forEach(photo => {
                let result = `
                <img src="${photo.urls.regular}" alt="" />
                <a href="${photo.links.downowload}">
                `;
                $('#result').append(result);
            });
        });
};
```

вот мой HTML:

```
    <section class="mobile-img">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Photos" class="photo-input" />
       <button id="searchPhotos">Search</button>
       <div id="result"></div>
   </section>
```

Comment: а вы видите [в документации](https://unsplash.com/documentation#response-8) атрибут `results`? что приходит вам в ответе?

Comment: Увидел, спасибо за ответ, немного невнимателен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно убрать ключ result, и ещё кстати let лучше заменить на const

```
        data.forEach(photo => {
            const result = `
            <img src="${photo.urls.regular}" alt="" />
            <a href="${photo.links.downowload}">
            `;
            $('#result').append(result);
        });
```